# grails runtime calculation in gsp page

Tags: grails, runtime, gsp

In my grails project I have an Invoice domain class. In this class I have amount value, discount, VAT etc. Discount and VAT are represented with two select.

In gsp I've added another field, called total, that shows the final value of the invoice. I would like that, when user changes value of discount, or of VAT, the total value changes.

For similar issue I've used a remoteFunction that, after passing parameters to a controller method, updates via javascript the value of the amount but in this case I don't know how to refer current values selected  in gsp by user.

Comment: use a simple javascript function to do the calculations

Comment: as I've written in post, with similar issues I've used a remoteFunction, so I've used a controller method for calculation and javascript to update value. The issue is about parameter to pass to controller, because I don't know how to pass it...can you give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

given the form with some fields in your GSP:

```
<g:textField name="discount" value="${discount}"/>
<g:textField name="vat" value="${vat}"/>
```

you can use a function like this (in `jquery`) to pass and receive the data to the controller:

```
function send(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'${createLink( controller:'your_controller', action:'someAction' )}',
    data:{ discount:$( '#discount' ).val(), vat:$( '#vat' ).val() }
}).done( function( data ){
  console.info( data );
} );
```